# Decomposition of $A(\vec{x})$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-programming

I have a matrix $A(\vec{x})$ and I want to show that there does not exist an $\vec{x}$ for which $A(\vec{x})\vec{x}=\vec{0}.$ This function $A$ has the property that $A(-\vec{x})(-\vec{x})\neq -A(\vec{x})\vec{x}.$ This function may be continuous, but it is probably not smooth.

I can perform an inverse iteration algorithm (or a power iteration) to find that the lowest eigenvalue of $A(\vec{x})$ is nonzero, but I'm not sure if this is 1. correct since $A$ is a function of $x$ and 2. shows what I want.

Do you have any advice on how to proceed in a way that shows what I want? Perhaps linear programming would be useful?

Comment: How does $A(\vec x)$ depend on $\vec x$ exactly?

Comment: You have to assume $\vec{x} \ne \vec{0}$, since trivially $A(\vec{0})\vec{0} = \vec{0}$.

Comment: I was hoping for something nonspecific, but I can give more details on my specific function if it would be helpful.

$A(\vec{x})=B^T\Theta(\vec{x})B$ where $\Theta(\vec{x})$ is chosen such that the result of $\Theta(\vec{x})B\vec{x}$ is positive (could be zero) everywhere.

Effectively this means that I find $\vec{b}=B\vec{x}$ and then zero out the negative entries before multiplying it by $B^T.$

Comment: What is the definition of $\Theta(\vec{x})$? And what do you assume for $B$?

Comment: $\Theta(\vec{x})$ is a diagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are either $1$ or $0.$ Diagonal entry $i$ is $1$ if $B_{ij}x_j\geq 0$ and zero otherwise.

We don't really know much about $B.$ We know that for $\Theta$ equal to the identity matrix that A is positive semi-definite. We also know that $B$ is rectangular with more rows than columns.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, let's require that $A(-\vec{x})(-\vec{x}) \ne -A(\vec{x})\vec{x}$ for all $\vec{x} \ne \vec{0}$.

Then it is still possible that there is $\vec{x} \ne \vec{0}$ such that $A(\vec{x})\vec{x} = \vec{0}$.

For a one-dimensional example, take $A(x) = x - 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then clearly
$$A(-x)(-x) = -x(-x-1) = x^2+x \ne -x^2 + x = -(x-1)x =-A(x)x
$$
for all $x \ne 0$, but $
A(1) \cdot 1 = 0$.